# Make flex item grow past (larger) than flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to simulate the hover effect that [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/browse) uses on it's "row of cards" that display the shows that are currently available to watch.

When you hover on a card, the item grows (seemingly) larger than the size of the row that it's contained in.

I'm using flexbox and have a `.row` and `.card` items inside the row. I've tried using `transform: scale(1.5)` and this works except it does not grow the card larger than the size of the row. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I have not understand well your problem. When I tried on JsFiddle, I have the result you seem to wish. Element hovered is bigger than the parent element "row".

```
.row{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
}

.cards{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

.cards:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="cards">1</div>
  <div class="cards">1</div>
  <div class="cards">1</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nesquimo/vbb8td62/1/

Comment: You got it! Sorry, I should have provided an example. Thanks.